# Git can't run editor but it definitely exists

Tags: git

I've run into a very strange problem where Git says it start can't my editor, even though it *definitely* exists and works:

```
$ git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/nano
$ git rebase -i main
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... fatal: cannot run /usr/bin/nano: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor '/usr/bin/nano'
$ ls -l /usr/bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 254048 Apr 12  2021 /usr/bin/nano
```

What could cause this? I'm using Git 2.39.3 on Rocky 8.8. The only thing I can think of is that I'm running the Git command from an NFS directory, but that shouldn't really matter should it?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the `git` install was actually an Apptainer app, so the `/usr/bin/nano` it is looking for is actually not present in the Apptainer container. Ugh.